# Php Exception get value

Tags: php, exception

I'm trying to catch an exception and I find it quite well, but something happened and I do not know if it is possible to do.It turns out what is wrong and I wish that I have control. I want to know exactly where and why it occurred. For instance :

I assign numbers dynamically to a table in my DB build the case (should never happen but anyway) where you were two equal numbers and this is the error I get:

```
"error":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2-105' for key 'evento_id_2'"
```

Actually there was a doubling of numbers (in this case 2-105) but I wonder if there is a way to get only the case where there was duplication to show the user the exact error and not the entire message.

Comment: So what is it you want? The error itself is a violation of an integrity constraint, but you only want it to say "duplicate entry '2-105'..." Or what?

Comment: Of course, the error is that, but what I want to do (if possible) value is knowing that the error occurred in this case was 105.

Comment: So if I've understood you correctly, you simply want to retrieve `2-105` and ignore the rest?

Comment: Yes! is what I need, I wanted to know if there is any property or function to do so or if the string rescued only error

Comment: There's no magic way to retrieve it, but you could use RegEx to retrieve it: `'/^SQLSTATE[23000].*1062 Duplicate entry \'(\d-\d{3})\'/'` might work

Comment: @Phroggyy OK! thank you very much, if you could put it in response to close the post appreciate it, let's see what we do: D!

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve this value from error message?  I would assume this error occurs on an insert or update attempt, so I would guess you already have the values stored in a variable.

Comment: What I do is go a basis (which may have different number of values), I would like to capture this error to inform the user where the error occurred (I allow to assign a range which dynamically, I take those values and gender numbers) for example, if the entered 100 and 110 generated the 101, 102 .... etc. And in another field you can put a range to double and for that I need to capture exactly where it occurred.

Comment: @Phroggyy You say making it a preg_match ??

Comment: Well, that's possibly the best way to do it. However, as @MikeBrant points out, you should already have the number as a variable somewhere, so I don't see how you can't have it.